# Двойной вызов конструктора глобального статического объекта?

Tags: c++

В прекомпилированном заголовке создается статический объект.

```
#pragma once

#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class globale {
  public:
    int A;
     globale::globale() {
        A++;
        std::cout << "\n1";
        std::cout << "\nA=" << A;
    }
};
static globale object_;
```

Главный код:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

int main()
{
    std::cout << "\n\n\nobject_.A=" << object_.A;
    std::cout << "\n";
    std::system("pause");
}
```

В итоге globale object_; формируется дважды. То есть дважды вызывается конструктор.
Если переместить

```
static globale object_;
```

после

```
#include "stdafx.h"
```

то всё нормально.

1. Это вызов одного и того же объекта?
2. Почему так происходит?
3. Можно ли это исправить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Какие cpp-файлы есть в проекте? Если есть `stdafx.cpp`, то я буду не удивлен созданию двух разных статических объектов: по одному на каждый cpp-файл проекта.

Решение - переместить определение статического объекта в cpp-файл. Если требуется использование этого объекта в других файлах проекта, то необходимо переписать код. Например, использовать ключевое слово `extern`, говорящее компилятору искать данный символ в других файлах, а не в текущем.

Comment: Теперь я въехал. 

А любой cpp файл включаемый выше или ниже в файле где main(){} называется модулем?

Или в самом компиляторе во вкладке 
обозреватель решений-файлы исходного кода.
надо его добавлять?

компилятор vs 2010.


То есть модуль это больше относится к компилятору?

Comment: Любой cpp-файл, включенный в проект, т.е. обрабатываемый компилятором отдельно, является модулем. Если же Вы сделаете `#include <smth.cpp>` внутри своего `main.cpp`, то просто все содержимое `smth.cpp` включиться в файл `main.cpp`, т.е. `smth.cpp` компилятором не будет обработан отдельно.